# Codeigniter login system HMVC

Tags: php, codeigniter, module, hmvc

I just installed Codeigniter HMVC and I really like the way it works but I am new to it. My question is how would I check on login? I know I have to make a login module. And afterwards I went into the core folder and added this to the MX_Loader

```
function __construct(){
    $this->load->helper('url');
    redirecht('login');
}
```

But it doesn't recognise the helper command. Am I doing something wrong? I wanted to check on sessions on this page and if the session doesn't exist I wanted to redirect it to the login module. How am I supposed to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You see you type "redirecht" ? And if you want to check login on each controller, you can add a MY_Controller in "core" folder, then extend it. It is the easiest way.

Comment: I did extend MY_Controller but it doesn't react on it. If I type redirect('login') in it for example it doesn't do anything. Although it does give me errors if I type an error in it. And sorry for the typo I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

for this  you have to include / autoload the session library.

Try this following example..

open the "application/config/autoload.php file and set the following.

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
$autoload['helpers'] = array('url');
```

in your login controller ( in which you validating the user account exist in the database), once you are done with the database verification, add the below lines

```
$session_array = array('admin_id' => "1",'username' => "admin"); // here the "1" and the string "admin" are just for example. modify the array key and value as per your requirement. 
$this->session->set_userdata('user_logged_in', $session_array);
 redirect('admin/dashboard', 'refresh');
```

By this line, the session will be added into the application. For evaluation, in your function __construct, add the below lines.

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    if(!$this->session->userdata('user_logged_in')){
     redirect('login');
    }   
}
```

hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks it is usefull but not really what I was looking for. VincentDecaux actually answered my question.